# How to compile this program without coding knowledge?

Tags: python, github, compile, source-code, elasticsearch

Please forgive my illeteracy as far as coding goes but I am trying to set up a program I found on github and although I don't have much coding knowledge I was able by following wome tutorial to do some of the part for the installation but I am still confused as to how I should compile it , what toolchain to use and how to do it .
the programme is this one :
https://github.com/EdjoLabs/image-match

I have managed to install elasticsearch so far and I have installed anaconda as recomanded but that's about it, spent the week-end trying without luck ...(I even tried the containerized version using docker but again not enough knowledge on my end to make it work...)
If you can help me interprete and allow me to have a user friendly tutorial on how to build this in my windows OS and have it with a user friendly interface that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help a thousand time

Comment: It's Python, you don't compile it. What have you done exactly and where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Gronostaj, I installed Elasticsearch as recomanded , then I downloaded the repository put it in my C drive , ran the cmd on anaconda , made sure to be on the repository using "cd" and ran the installation of install numpy, install scipy
pip install image_match, when I tried to install image_match it started downloading and then had thousands of red line showing errors....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool you linked is a python **package**, it means it won't compile into a standalone program but you can include it in one.

Without any programming unfortunately you can't use it (as the program need some user interface, select images, call the package, display results...)

Comment: Knowing this, I will hire the help of an actual developer as this will require more professional work.